# Resultant of two special trinomials

Tags: polynomials, resultants

Consider $f(x)=x^n-x^s-1$ and $g(x)=x^i-x^j-1$ , I want to find $Resultant(f,g)$. It is well known that it is determinant of a Sylvester matrix but, I am finding it to obscure to evaluate in that way.

Is there some known result for such special cases ?

It is known that the Discriminant of a trinomial has a closed form expression. ([LINK](http://www.ijpam.eu/contents/2012-74-1/5/5.pdf))

Comment: Posted some months ago to m.se, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1943631/resultant-of-two-special-trinomials but with no answers.

Comment: But why the votes to close? Wouldn't it be nice to have a closed-form formula for the resultant as a function of $n,s,i,j$ – or to have an acknowledgement that no such formula is known?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I would like to add that, if we can find a formula for Resultant of general trinomials, then the resilt will subsume this paper. http://www.ijpam.eu/contents/2012-74-1/5/5.pdf

Comment: I made some calculations for the easiest non-trivial case $s=j=1$. Let's call the resultant $A(n,i)$. Then $A(n,2)=- floor(\varphi^{n-2})+((n-1)\mod 2)$ (https://oeis.org/A001350) and $A(n,3)$ is http://oeis.org/A001945 (with an offset). $A(n,4)$ is not in OEIS.

Comment: And another observation: $|(A(n,n+k))_k|$ seems to be periodic with period $n-1$.